# Election page shows contradictory info about the number of candidates

Tags: discussion, user-interface, election

This is certainly a minor issue but I still decided to report it, just in case

[image]

Although it says `candidates 6` the ballot contains 5 candidates only.

Comment: [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412483/1328704) is also relevant.

Comment: @JNat I wonder if one could make this less confusing by replacing with something like `nominations 6` and `candidates 5`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the "nomination" itself best describes what happened:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/election/2?tab=nomination#post-620218

[image]

Comment: That raises another question: How did they manage to nominate themselves during the election phase?

Comment: @DonaldDuck bug :)